# c# ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, exception

I Have this piece of code:

```
    private List<...> LayPrices;
    public Decimal BestLayOdds
    {
        get
        {
            if (LayPrices.Count > 0)
            {
                return LayPrices[0].dOdds;
            }
            return 1000.0M;   
        }
    }
```

The Problem is that sometimes the List has items, but it does not enter inside the 'if' statement.

Check the images below of a debug session:

[image]

How is that even possible?

But if I force it to return the first item, on the last return statement, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException even though the list has elements. Check the nest image:

[image]

Is there any problem with my code or it is just a stupid bug?

**Update:**

The `LayPrices` List is only instantiated on the class Constructor: `LayPrices = new List<PriceStruct>();`.

It is only getting filled with items on one method, whith the following code:

```
    LayPrices.Clear();
    foreach (PriceSize priceSize in exchangePrices.availableToLay)
    {
          PriceStruct lay = new PriceStruct();
          lay.dOdds = (Decimal)priceSize.price;
          lay.dAmount = (Decimal)priceSize.size;

          LayPrices.Add(lay);
   }
```

Concurrency issues and threading were my first clue, so I did put a lock(LayPrices) and the problem still persisted:

[image: lock]

So I think it is not a concurrency issue.

Comment: How is `LayPrices` instantiated and filled? Any threading going around?

Comment: Either I'm missing something, or we won't be able to see the problem from your code. Could you add the setting of LayPrices as well? (or show every place where it gets modified/instanciated).

Comment: form where LayPrices is getting the input? In above code LayPrices object is not initialized.

Comment: Is the array accessed from separate threads (race conditions)? Perhaps your debug session is using new code against an older compilation that actually has different logic?

Comment: Do you have any property getters that set or fill `LayPrices` that the Visual Studio debugger might be evaluating?

Comment: If everything seems fine, then clean the solution and rebuilt it. Sometimes it solves the problem.

Comment: +1 to this question. You have a truly X-Files situation going on there. Kudos :)

Comment: Are you really, really sure there isn't any threading going on in your app? That would be my first likely culprit for this strange behaviour. Is `LayPrices` being accessed by multiple threads?

Comment: Concurrency issues and threading were my first clue, so I did put a `lock(LayPrices)` and the problem still persisted... So I think it is not a concurrency issue

Comment: @JoaquimAnacleto can you show the code for how you locked it? If you did it right and it persisted this truely is a case for X-Files ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
It was indeed concurrency issues, even though I don't use threads explicitly, I use events and I thought event handling was synchronized (It is synchronized right?).

If I add locks everywhere I read or add to the list, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Put `Debug.Assert(LayPrices.Count > 0)` in the getter before the `if` statement and you'll see that the `List` is in fact empty.

The only reasonable explanation is that you are populating the list either in some other thread and you have a race condition or in a property getter that only gets fired by the debugger (you could also be populating the list in a catch clause up the callstack but I imagine you would have figured that out by yourself)

In order to get a better answer please include all code that populates your list. No only the code you *think* should run, but *all* the properties, constructors or methods that add or remove items from the list.

Comment: I did that and you are right! The assertion fails, because the list is in fact empty. Now I have to figure out why the debug tells me it is not. Thanks for the help.